# Arraylist of images(All Image selected from Gallery) convert info single pdf

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pick multiple image from gallery and just want to convert all images one  after another in single pdf file and want to save it on Documents Folder.

```
public class GalleryImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
    private ArrayList<Uri> imageUris;
    private static final int PIC_IMAGE_CODE = 0;
    int position = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_image);

    imageSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.imageswitch);

    imageUris = new ArrayList<>();

    imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            return imageView;
        }
    });
}


public void prevBtn(View view) {
    if (position > 0) {
        position--;
        imageSwitcher.setImageURI(imageUris.get(position));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No previous Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void nextBtn(View view) {
    if (position < imageUris.size() - 1) {
        position++;
        imageSwitcher.setImageURI(imageUris.get(position));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No More Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void openGalleryBtn(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setType("image/*");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Image(s)"), PIC_IMAGE_CODE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PIC_IMAGE_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    imageUris.add(imageUri);
                }
                imageSwitcher.setImageURI(imageUris.get(0));
                position = 0;

            } else {
                Uri imageuri = data.getData();
                imageUris.add(imageuri);
                imageSwitcher.setImageURI(imageUris.get(0));
                position = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void CreatePDF(View view) {
    File file = getOutputFile();
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

            for (int i = 0; i < imageUris.size(); i++) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUris.get(i).getPath());
                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(350, 500, (i + 1)).create();
                PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
                pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            pdfDocument.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private File getOutputFile() {
    File root = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "My PDF Folder");

    boolean isFolderCreated = true;

    if (!root.exists()) {
        isFolderCreated = root.mkdir();
    }

    if (isFolderCreated) {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "PDF_" + timeStamp;

        return new File(root, imageFileName + ".pdf");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Folder is not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
 }
}
```

Thats all my row code.

Now i am going show the error when i try to run this app.

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:40: open  failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:65)
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseCanvas.java:113)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1600)
    at com.anoxsoftech.scannerbuddy.GalleryImage.CreatePDF(GalleryImage.java:131)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

It is possible to help, where is the error? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file)` That should be more like Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUries.get(i)); if decodeStream was overloaded like that.

Comment: Further you have a java.lang.NullPointerException because your bitmap is null. See your log. The message tells you all.

Comment: I tried decode but i doesnt work.

Comment: @blackapps how can i solve?

Comment: Of course that does not work. I told you that.

Comment: so what will be the solution can you help me?

Comment: If you only say that it does not work an not tell wich error you get and when.... Then you should not expect too much help.

Comment: when I wrote this line Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUries.get(i)); its show runtime error , its say :  incompatible types: Uri cannot be converted to InputStream

Comment: That is no runtime error but a compile time error. Indeed decodeStream expects a -input-stream. Not an uri. Well make an inputstream for that uri i would say.

Comment: InputStream inStream =getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUris.get(i));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);

I wrote those line. Right now no error but doesnt generate pdf and doesnt save anything.

here is full source code : https://github.com/KayesFahim/ScannerBuddy 
you can check and help me.

Comment: No decodeStream does not generate a pdf. It generates a bitmap. Please help your self by better reporting what goes wrong.

Comment: nothing gone wrong. application working fine just pdf doesnt create and save

Comment: Well then create and save goes wrong i would say. Deep into it. Debug! Where is the Toast() in that catch block to inform the user?

Comment: I could solved already. Thnx

Comment: Wel.. tell what the problem was and how you solved it. You could post your new code. We are busy with you 16 hours so would like to know of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of my problem. I tried my self and took help from stackoverflow others similar questions . Some of contributer also helped me. Thanks all.

```
public class GalleryImage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button createpdfBtn;
ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
private ArrayList<Uri> imageUris;
private static final int PIC_IMAGE_CODE = 0;
int position = 0;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_image);

    imageSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.imageswitch);
    createpdfBtn = findViewById(R.id.createPdf);


    imageUris = new ArrayList<>();

    imageSwitcher.setFactory(() -> new ImageView(getApplicationContext()));
}


public void prevBtn(View view) {
    if (position > 0) {
        position--;
        imageSwitcher.setImageURI(imageUris.get(position));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No previous Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void nextBtn(View view) {
    if (position < imageUris.size() - 1) {
        position++;
        imageSwitcher.setImageURI(imageUris.get(position));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No More Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void openGalleryBtn(View view) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        requestPermissions(permission, 401);
    } else {
        OpenGallery();
    }

}

private void OpenGallery() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setType("image/*");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Image(s)"), PIC_IMAGE_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PIC_IMAGE_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    imageUris.add(imageUri);
                }

            } else {
                Uri imageuri = data.getData();
                imageUris.add(imageuri);
            }
            imageSwitcher.setImageURI(imageUris.get(0));
            position = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void CreatePDF(View view) {
    File file = getOutputFile();
    if (file != null) {
        try {

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

            for (int i = 0; i < imageUris.size(); i++) {
                InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUris.get(i));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), (i + 1)).create();
                PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 612,816, true);
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
                pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GalleryImage.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            pdfDocument.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "PDf Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "PDf Save Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private File getOutputFile() {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"Scanner Buddy Folder");

    boolean isFolderCreated = true;

    if (!root.exists()) {
        isFolderCreated = root.mkdir();
    }

    if (isFolderCreated) {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "SC_PDF_" + timeStamp;

        return new File(root, imageFileName + ".pdf");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Folder is not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
  }

}
```

If anyone get help from there then its a lot for me. Happy coding